# How should I have edited this question differently?

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question, flagging

Recently I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448694/sqrt-cbrt-what-if-dont-want-squared-or-cubed-root-but-any-root#comment64325827_38448762) that a new [bang](https://duckduckgo.com/bang) had been added to [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/), and I was curious about how long the new bang has been around. A Google search led me to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88780/122501):

> ***Is there a way to get the overall list of all [DuckDuckGo Bangs](https://duckduckgo.com/bang), together with the categories and history of each bang being introduced or modified?***

For some reason, it was closed as a duplicate of [another question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87678/122501) that only asked for a list of bangs, not a list of bangs *with categories and history*. So I [flagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/122501) it as "in need of moderator intervention" (apologies if that link doesn't work; I couldn't figure out how to get a public link to the flag):

> This question should be reopened because it is not a duplicate of the linked question. That question only asks for a list of bangs, whereas this one asks for a list of bangs with history.

The flag was marked as "helpful" with this note:

> Please suggest an edit indicating that the duplicate does not answer the history portion and the question will be pulled into the Reopen queue

So I suggested an [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76351) with the comment "added note about why this question is not a duplicate", in which I added this paragraph to the end of the question:

> The question [Comprehensive list of all available !bangs on DuckDuckGo.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87678/122501) is similar to this one, but while that question only asks for a list of bangs, this question is asking for a list of bangs *with history and categories*.

To my surprise, the edit was rejected by two users with this reason:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I tried to follow the instructions given in response to the flag that I raised, but I guess the exact edit that I made wasn't what I was supposed to do. **What was incorrect about the edit that I made, and how should I have properly edited the question to indicate that it is not a duplicate?**

Comment: I was the one that encouraged you to make the edit, so I sincerely apologize for the response you received.  I should have left a comment on the question indicating my position. You did absolutely nothing wrong.

Comment: @jonsca Thank you. I was just a bit confused, but it looks like this meta discussion has cleared up the issue, so it seems that the system is working well! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit summary could have been a bit more detailed, but I think those two reviewers were incorrect.

We often guide people how to indicate that a question isn't a duplicate to another, and part of that guidance is to edit the marked duplicate explaining how it's not a duplicate with a link to what it's supposedly a duplicate of.

Such is the risk of a community-moderated site. Occasionally the hive-mind gets it wrong.

I've edited your change into the question.

Now, whether that convinces others enough to cast re-open votes is a different matter.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to know that I was on the right track. By the way, it looks like you might have accidentally added the same paragraph twice in [your edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/88780/3).

Comment: Do note that this is _my opinion_, not official policy.

Comment: Of course. I was just unsure of whether or not I was doing something blatantly wrong, but now I have some indication that I *probably* wasn't.